# Confused about Interfaces. How do I call an interface method in one class and define it in another?

Tags: android, interface, callback

I'm new to interfaces and I'm trying to do the following. What am I missing?

```
public class MyAdapter implements ItemManager.DoThisInterface {
    ...
    @Override
    doThis() {
        // Do things specific to my adapter. Define action hre.
    }
}
```

The interface is defined in the Item Manager, which does not know what needs to be done. The adapter should define the actions.

```
public class ItemManager {
    ....
    private void onCertainEvent() {
        doThis(); // do whatever is overriden in adapter. 
                  // this is kind of a placeholder for what i expect to be defined
                  // in the adapter.
                  // (this fails to compile because it can't call straight to the interface method)
    }

    // interface declaration
    public interface DoThisInterface {
        doThis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create an object.

```
MyAdapter ma=new MyAdapter();
ma.doThis();
```

Call this and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I don't want the adapter to call 'doThis'. I want it to be defined in the adapter, but I want the ItemManager to invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a `DoThisInterface` instance on the class `ItemManager`, and save it in the instance field, then use the instance to call the interface method, like this

```
public class ItemManager {

    private DoThisInterface mDoThisInterface;
    ....
    private void onCertainEvent() {
        if(mDoThisInterface != null){
            mDoThisInterface.doThis();
        } 
    }

    public void setDoThisInterface(DoThisInterface doThisInterface){
        mDoThisInterface = doThisInterface;
    }

    // interface declaration
    public interface DoThisInterface {
        doThis();
    }
}
```